# Mysql Insert/Update is so Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a laravel application which must `insert/update` thousands of records per second in a `for loop`. my problem is that my Database `insert/update` rate is **100-150** writes per second . I have increased the amount of RAM dedicated to my database but got no luck.
[image]

is there any way to increase the write rate for mysql to thousands of records per second ?
please provide me configurations.

My storage engine is **InnoDB**

Comment: It is pretty hard to give you a definitive answer without knowing the hardware and software environment you are running the mysql instance under. Does the table in question have proper index coverage for the updates? Are we talking about simple inserts and updates or are they dependent on some other db operation?

Comment: Its simple Insert/update . I have 8 GB of RAM and a core i5 CPU. its not a code problem . its a misconfiguration

Comment: There are a lot of factors which control the speed of inserts, host server configuration, MySQL installation configuration (data volumes, etc), table design - field types, indexes, etc. Can you provide more information about these areas to let us help you more?

Comment: "its not a code problem . its a misconfiguration" -- how did you determine that?

Comment: Insert/update issue might be because of Indexes. We can help you only if you share your table schema with us.

Comment: You need to consider looking at your IOPs limit and how much it bursts.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552637/very-slow-eloquent-insert-update-queries-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Innodb storage is care about ACID transaction it will make sure your data(insert/update) commit to disk that why take the time:

1. Considering about the columns which frequently change(insert/update), you should not indexing on that column.
2. if you always need big data of DML operation try to avoid `auto-commit=0`.but it not good if server crush or some fallen.
3. turning your query if your DML operation bases on subquery:

Example:

```
UPDATE TEST SET NAME='XXXX' WHERE (subquery).
```

Answer (score 1):

- Batch `INSERTs` -- That is, do one `INSERT` with up to 100 rows.
- Group into transactions -- `BEGIN; do several things; COMMIT;`
- Change `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` (see documentation for discussion of speed versus security tradeoff.)

If you need further discussion, show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the queries involved.